# Xamarin Forms - Access CookieStore from a WebView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, session-cookies, setcookie, cookiestore

I'm creating a login page to a website and I want to use the cookies retrieved from this site to perform actions automatically

So I followed [this](https://blog.wislon.io/posts/2016/01/24/xamforms-quick-and-dirty-cookies-access) article to access cookies from a given website,

From sniffing the packets between my device and the server, I received this very SetCookie:

```
Set-Cookie: AppCookie=COOKIEVALUE; expires=Tue, 13 Jul 2021 21:35:00 GMT; path=/; secure; samesite=lax; httponly
```

Although after retrieveing the Cookies for the site I don't get this cookie

Could anyone think of a reason for that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use custom renderer to retrieving the Cookies.

**On Android:**

```
var cookieHeader = CookieManager.Instance.GetCookie(url);
```

[image]

You could download the source file from the GitHub:
https://github.com/WendyZang/CookiesWebView

**On iOS:**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(WebView), typeof(CustomWebViewRenderer))]
namespace Sample.iOS
{
public class CustomWebViewRenderer : WkWebViewRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            NavigationDelegate = new CustomNavigationDelegate();
        } 
    }
}

public class CustomNavigationDelegate : WKNavigationDelegate
{
    public override void DidFinishNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
    {
        webView.Configuration.WebsiteDataStore.HttpCookieStore.GetAllCookies((cookies) =>
        {

        });
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: I have already did it, that's how I retrieve the cookies, for some reason part of the cookies are not showing.

Comment: Do you get all the cookies? If yes, how do you set the cookie? Have you check the cookie one by one?

Comment: Apparently I don't, cookies are set by the server I am communicating with (Set-Cookie), Weird thing is that I checked it on a physical device (Not emulated) and it works smoothly.

Comment: The emulator is different with the physical device. Maybe the peroperty seetings of emulator cause this error. Glad it works well on physical device.